# Imposing zero mean condition in FEM

Tags: finite-element, elliptic-pde

I wanted to solve a periodic elliptic equation of the form $$-\nabla\cdot(A\nabla u)=-\nabla\cdot F$$ on $Y=[0,2\pi)^d$ using FreeFem++, where $A$ and $F$ are $Y$-periodic. The space of solutions is $H^1_{per}(Y)/\mathbb{R}$, which can also be seen as the space of periodic $H^1$ functions with zero mean. How does one typically impose the zero mean condition in FEM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this.

The first approach is given by Lagrange multipliers and is well explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112280/zero-average-in-solution-to-laplace-problem-with-lagrange-multipliers). You have to solve an extended linear system where you impose the solution to be zero-mean.

The second approach, which may be easier, is to modify the system so that *one nodal value* inside the domain is clamped to zero, i.e., you impose $u_{i^*} = 0$ for some index $i^*$, where $\mathbf{u} = (u_1, \ldots, u_N)^\top$ is the vector of nodal values of your discrete solution $u_h$. This is obtained by replacing an equation $u_{i^*} = 0$ on the $i^*$-th line of your FEM linear system. Then, your final solution $u_h$ is obtained as
$$
u_h \leftarrow u_h - \frac{1}{|Y|}\int_{Y} u_h,
$$ 
where $|Y| = (2\pi)^d$, which is trivially zero-mean.

Comment: I do not get why the second method leads to zero mean solution? is this enforced in the strong sense?

Comment: $\int_{Y} \left(u_h - \frac{1}{|Y|}\int_{Y} u_h \right) = \int_Y u_h - \int_Y u_h = 0$